# How do I import a Visual C++ project into Qt Creator?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt-creator

I have been working with the commercial version of Qt on Windows for some time, so have a large collection of Visual Studio projects (*vcproj* files).
I would like to begin moving these projects into Qt Creator — I have certainly moved some of them "by hand", and can make that work — but it seems like there ought to be (might be?) a Visual Studio import script or app or capability of some kind.

Does anybody know of such a thing, or of a definable set of procedures to move a project from one to the other?

Comment: Do these projects already have qmake files?

Comment: no, they dont have valid qmake files, since once they are part of visual studio, its the vcproj file that matters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can export to a pro file (or maybe a pri file, can't remember) from the Qt menu in VS.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps make a Makefile which calls devenv to build your project/solution from the command-line and the use "Import from a Makefile-based project" from the new menu.